# Removing <ul> tag from editor

Tags: magento-1.8, wysiwyg

I have added the following code to the editor:

```
<li><a href="#" class="xxx"></a></li>
```

After saving it automatically changed to :

```
<ul><li><a href="#" class="xxx"></a></li></ul>
```

Is there a method to avoid adding `<ul>` tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Theoretically adding the following code to `js/mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/setup.js` may help:

```
valid_children : '+body[li]'
```

if it will do the job you may think about how to do it w/o overriding core JS file.